# Orbital variations

Tags: orbital-motion, relativity, geodesics

My question relates to relativity and the warping of spacetime.  If the geodesics approaching the star are coplanar with the ecliptic how can polar planetary orbits form?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Currently, your question is very minimalistic, and only understandable to people who already know exactly what you're talking about. We prefer our questions to try to be approachable to a wider audience than just the asker and the potential answerer, so you could help out and explain a bit more - what's a "polar planetary orbit", which ecliptic are you talking about, and is it a well-known fact that geodesics approach the star coplanar with it or did you read that in some obscure book from fifty years ago?

Answer (score 2):

If we take some object approaching a star along a geodesic then the angular momentum of that object about the centre of the star picks out a natural axis:

[image: Orbit]

If we consider a Schwarzschild metric (NB this applies only if the star is not rotating) we can choose this axis to be the $\theta$ axis then the symmetry means the geodesic must lie in the plane defined by $\theta = \pi/2$. So in these circumstances the geodesic must lie in a single plane.

So far so good, but this argument ony applies to a system that is not rotating. If we have a rotating star or a stellar system with rotating planets or acretion disk then the geometry is now described by the Kerr metric and this has a natural axis that corresponds with the angular momentum of the star, planets or whatever.

If our object is approaching in the plane of the ecliptic then the angular momentum of the object lines up with the angular momentum of the stellar system and the geometry is still axially symmetric. That means our arguments still apply, and the orbit of the object will be confined to a plane - the plane of the ecliptic.

But the object can of course approach the star from any direction, and it must still follow a geodesic. The difference is that the geometry is now not axially symmetric and the geodesic the object follows will not lie in a single plane. So a polar orbit is of course possible, but instead of being confined to a plane it must rotate.

This is basically the [Lens-Thirring effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession), and for all but extremely dense and rapidly rotating objects the effect is very, very small. The Gravity Probe B attempted to measure the effect for orbits about the Earth, and just managed it to a precision of about 15%.

I've gone on a bit, because I wasn't sure exactly what you are asking. The tl;dr version is that of course polar orbits are possible, but they won't be closed.

Comment: Thank you John.  Let me give some thought to this answer I think this clears it up--if not I will edit my question as others have requested.